# What are some good ways to identify nfs clients that cause high load on nfs server

Tags: monitoring, nfs

Sometimes my nfs4 server is under high load. Is there any good tools identify which client causes it. running iotop and nfsstat on nfs server shows only general load information which does not help to identify nfs clients. I do not want to iterate over all possible nfs clients and run mentioned tools on them.

The best solution I have come up with is to run tcpdump on server and then sort ip addresses by traffic volume related to nfs. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use iptop (http://sourceforge.net/projects/iptop/) to monitor tcp traffic and out can use wireshark extension https://github.com/kofemann/wireshark_lua to watch your nfs clients.